# Intercept in survreg and coxph

Tags: r

I'm trying to compare my semi-parametric proportional hazard model and accelerated failure time model with exponential baseline. The co-efficients should be 'the same', but with different sign.

I'm using coxph and survreg functions in R. Coxph gives me results without intercept and surverg gives me results with intercept. I understand that I can't turn on the intercept for the baseline hazard of coxph. Is there any way to turn the intercept off for survreg? I have attached my results below.

Also, is it important to have an intercept with the covariates, when my aim is to understand the treatment effect?

```
> coxph(Surv(Time,Reason=="I")~AgeG, data = PTARdata)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(Time, Reason == "I") ~ AgeG, data = PTARdata)


           coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z       p
AgeG0   -3.4241    0.0326    1.005 -3.406 6.6e-04
AgeG1    0.1232    1.1311    0.154  0.803 4.2e-01
AgeG2   -0.2774    0.7578    0.137 -2.023 4.3e-02
AgeG3   -0.0503    0.9509    0.146 -0.345 7.3e-01
AgeG4    0.2063    1.2292    0.203  1.014 3.1e-01
AgeG5   -0.1531    0.8581    0.147 -1.039 3.0e-01
AgeG6   -0.7706    0.4627    0.182 -4.238 2.3e-05

Likelihood ratio test=70.5  on 7 df, p=1.15e-12  

> PTAR.ph.age2<-survreg(Surv(Time,Reason=="I")~AgeG,data = PTARdata, dist='weibull',scale=1)
> summary(PTAR.ph.age2)

Call:
survreg(formula = Surv(Time, Reason == "I") ~ AgeG, data = PTARdata, 
    dist = "weibull", scale = 1)
              Value Std. Error       z       p
(Intercept)  8.9611     0.0891 100.588 0.00000
AgeG0        3.1638     1.0040   3.151 0.00163
AgeG1       -0.1332     0.1535  -0.868 0.38537
AgeG2        0.2740     0.1371   1.998 0.04571
AgeG3        0.0423     0.1458   0.290 0.77176
AgeG4       -0.2398     0.2031  -1.181 0.23778
AgeG5        0.1042     0.1465   0.712 0.47673
AgeG6        0.5469     0.1751   3.123 0.00179

Scale fixed at 1 

Weibull distribution
Loglik(model)= -5087.9   Loglik(intercept only)= -5115.2
        Chisq= 54.51 on 7 degrees of freedom, p= 1.9e-09 
Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 11
```

Comment: Cox regression models have no intercept by default. I think the question of comparing these 2 is better asked on CrossValidated, as it's a question of interpretation/methods and not of programming in itself. I flagged it to move to CrossValidated.

Comment: Why would you like to compare the coeffs of AFT and Cox model? and as Heroka points out that Cox does not have intercept at all.

Comment: I want to compare the coeffs of AFT and Cox, because they should be the same after transformation. I'm double checking my work, making sure I am doing the right thing (code etc).

Comment: How to turn off the intercept in a AFT model?